# How to get a parameter value from the current URL in views-view-fields.html.twig?

Tags: views, 8, theming

I need the argument value in the theme templates and using the `views-views-fields--view_name--block_1.jhtml.twig`.

---

I'm current getting the current URL like that:

```
{% set url = url('current')%}
```

Which outputs:

```
https://example.com/questions/12225
```

---

But I need only the **12225** value from the current url. How can I get the last parameter from the current URL in Twig?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use Twig's [`split`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html) filter, though I don't recommend scripting too much inside templates.

Instead I recommend to pass the value over to Twig from a preprocess function from inside your theme or a custom module via [`template_preprocess_views_view_fields`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/8.2.x).

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_views_view_fields().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables) {

  // Retrieve an array which contains the path pieces.
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();

  if ($current_path[0] == 'questions') {
    $variables['question_id'] = $current_path[1];
  }
}
```

And then inside your template print it for example like so:

```
{% if question_id %}
  <div id="{{ question_id }}">Question ID: {{ question_id }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know it is best way or not but can help you
You are using the {% set url = url('current>') %}
After dump, it turned out that's what

```
array(3) { 
    ["#markup"]=> string(23) "http://example.com/category" 
    ["#cache"]=> array(3) { 
         ["contexts"]=> array(2) { 
                [0]=> string(5) "route" 
                [1]=>string(8) "url.site" 
         } 
         ["tags"]=> array(0) { } 
         ["max-age"]=> int(-1) 
    } 
    ["#attached"]=> array(0) { } 
}
```

Convert array to sting

```
{% set url = url('<current>')['#markup'] %}

{{ url|split('/')|last }}
```

you will get the last value part of the URL

Comment: Is this a typo `'current>'` the trailing angle bracket?

Comment: <current> showing as blank in the comment so i have to type this but its value  will not changes after url change , aftrer cache flush its value change

Comment: Thanks for this! I used this code to add a class to a div in a Drupal Commerce checkout pane.

{% set url = url('<current>')['#markup'] %}{{ url|split('/')|last }}

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to get the url parameters, but the current path was only returning the path without the parameters.

The following solution worked for me in a page preprocess function, I haven't tried with views fields but it should work also.

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables) {

  // Retrieve an array which contains the path parameters.
  $variables['params']['parameter_name'] = $_GET['parameter_name'];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To fetch the current path with query string in views you can also use the [Views Current Path (Global: Current Path)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_current_path) module.

> Provides a Views field that displays the URL of the current page being viewed.

Comment: Nice module, but this is not what OP asked for.

Comment: Module is broken with Drupal 9 and discontinued