# How do I get a contextual filter argument in a template file?

Tags: 8, views

I use contextual filters for a view whose path is /path/langcode, where *langcode* is a contextual filter. How can I get *langcode* in a template file?

Comment: Check this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269697/how-to-get-a-parameter-value-from-the-current-url-in-views-view-fields-html-twig/269699

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the contextual filter argument from the route match:

```
  $variables['arg_0'] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('arg_0');
```

Usually the route parameters of contextual filters are named `arg_0`, `arg_1` etc. If it doesn't work, check the route definition of this View page with Devel (/devel/routes) or Drupal Console.

Dependent on the Twig template you might need to add a cache context as well:

```
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'route';
```